# Why the CSS style is not applied to the component in react after I use npm to install the package

Tags: reactjs, npm, gulp, browserify

everyone

I just started learning react and using npm recently, and I was trying to implement a react-select package today. After I render the component, I found the css style is not applied to the components. I need to import the css file in my index.html for it to work properly, am I missing something in my gulpfile? I use browserify to build my modules, here's my gulpfile code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil =require('gulp-util');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

gulp.task('default', function(){
var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    entries: ['./src/app.jsx'],
    transform: [reactify],
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    fullPaths: true
}));

function build(file) {
    if (file) gutil.log('Recompiling' + file);
    return bundler
        .bundle()
        .on('error',gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
};
build();
bundler.on('update',build);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: NPM doesn't have any magic. You will always have to incorporate styles into your own code in some way, just like you have to `require` the javascript. Depending on your setup, that could be `@import`ing a less or sass file from the vendor, concatenating vendor css with your own, including the file in your own distribution, or including the CDN version for optimal performance. What does your style stack look like right now?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I can find the css file included in the modules. So I was thinking maybe I can write some code in my gulpfile to tell browerify to include the styles automatically.

Comment: You can, but as I said in my comment, it depends on your current style stack which of the options I listed. What is your current style stack? CSS? SASS? LESS? Do you concatenate or minify?

Comment: I'm using CSS, and I concatenate them.

Comment: Then can't you just add this file to the ones you concatenate?

Comment: Yes, I can. I'm just wondering if there's a easier way to do this, I thought I missed something in my code since the style is not inherited from the package.

Comment: Easier than saying "hey, add this file too"? No. As I said - there's no magic in NPM. There are many gulp tasks and webpack loaders and browserify plugins to help, but none can eliminate the need for the developer to express her wishes.

Comment: Yeah, got that. As I said, I just began using these technologies recently, and usually the style comes with the component directly. So when I found this component not equipped with the style, I just thought "Did I miss something? I used the wrong command?" Anyway, thank you for clearing my concerns.